# How to correct type typeof class has no index?

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript class with a series of  static methods

```
 class MyClass{
   static Method01(){}
   static Method02(){}
   ...
   static Method0N(){}
 }
```

In some other class I get a parameter "action" and invoke:

```
 try{
    MyClass[action]()
 }catch(error){
     console.log(error)
 }
```

Linter warns me by saying:

```
 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof MyClass' has no index signature.ts
```

How can I skip this warning?

Answer (score 1):

You should somehow narrow your `action` variable to a string literal (static method name). How to achieve this depends on your use case.

```
const action = 'Method01';
// Or
let action = 'Method02' as const;
// Or
type Action = keyof typeof MyClass;
let action: Action = 'Method0N';

MyClass[action] // no warning
```